# How to remove minor ticks from "Framed" plots and overlay two plots?

Tags: plotting, ticks, frame

I have two plots, as seen below, Plot1 and Plot2 with a common x-axis. Each plot has a different range of y-axis and I overlay them. I want to remove the minor ticks from the frames of each plot and then overlay. How do I do this?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
xaxis1 = 0;
xaxis2 = 0.04;
yaxis1 = 0;
yaxis2 = 550;
PlotA = Plot[{5000*Sa + 100 }, {Sa, xaxis1, xaxis2 }, 
  PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotRange -> {{xaxis1, xaxis2}, {yaxis1, yaxis2}}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, Bold}, Frame -> True]

yaxis1 = 0;
yaxis2 = 0.8;
PlotB = Plot[{Sa^2 + Sa }, {Sa, xaxis1, xaxis2 }, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  PlotRange -> {{xaxis1, xaxis2}, {yaxis1, yaxis2}}, 
  LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, Bold}, Frame -> True]

Plot1 = Show[PlotA, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 10.5, Bold}, 
   Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}, ImagePadding -> 40, 
   FrameTicks -> {{All, All}, {All, None}}, AspectRatio -> 1];

Plot2 = Show[PlotB, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 10.5, Bold}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, All}}, 
   Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}, ImagePadding -> 40, 
   FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, Blue}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];
Overlay[{Plot1, Plot2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Please supply code and example of the Plots

Comment: Take a look at the Resource Function [CombinePlots](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/CombinePlots).

Comment: @Jagra I have edited the question to include the code and sample plot

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi It wasn't as useful since it doesn't address the question with regard to the Tick plots. I'm already using Overlay to combine plots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the CustomTicks package you can set the option `ShowMinorTicks` to True or False.

Another way is to list where you want the frame ticks to appear:

```
Plot1 = Show[PlotA, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 10.5, Bold}, 
   Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}, ImagePadding -> 40, 
   FrameTicks -> {{{100, 200, 300, 400, 500}, 
      All}, {{0.00, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04}, None}}, AspectRatio -> 1];

Plot2 = Show[PlotB, LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 10.5, Bold}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{None, {0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8}}, {None, All}}, 
   Frame -> {{False, True}, {False, False}}, ImagePadding -> 40, 
   FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, Blue}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];
```

[image]

Comment: How can I make the label print as "0.00" and not "0."

Comment: @Biotechgeek : The `FrameTicks` option has four parts: {{left, right}, {bottom, top}}.  Change the specification for the bottom frame ticks to `{{{0, "0.00"}, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04}`.  The 0.01, 0.02, ... say to put the label "0.01
 at 0.01, "0.02" at 0.02, ... .  The {0, "0.00"} says to put "0.00" at 0.

Answer (score 3):

```
{xrange, yrange1, yrange2} = {{0, .04}, {0, 550}, {0, .8}};
```

You can use a single `Plot` using the following steps:

1. Define a scaling function to rescale y values from the range `{0, .8}` to the range `{0, 550}`:

```
scalingFunction = Rescale[#, yrange2, yrange1] &;
```

2. Use `{5000*Sa + 100, scalingFunction[Sa^2 + Sa]}` in the first argument of `Plot`;
3. Use the function `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` with the option `"TicksLength" -> {.03, 0}` to get ticks with only the major ticks, and
4. Use `` Charting`ScaledTicks[{scalingFunction, InverseFunction[scalingFunction]}] `` to scale back the blue y-axis.

```
scalingFunction = Rescale[#, yrange2, yrange1] &;

Plot[{5000*Sa + 100, scalingFunction[Sa^2 + Sa]}, {Sa, xaxis1, xaxis2}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
 PlotRange -> {xrange, yrange1}, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, Bold},
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameStyle -> {{Automatic, Blue}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, "TicksLength" -> {.03, 0}], 
    Charting`ScaledTicks[{scalingFunction, InverseFunction[scalingFunction]}, 
     "TicksLength" -> {.03, 0}]}, {Automatic, None}}]
```

[image]